# Interpreting Interaction Effects Using Main Effects Between Models

Tags: regression, data-visualization, interaction

Traditionally, to investigate the interaction effects between 2 variables one would simply add the interaction term to their model. C ~ A + B + A:B. I feel fairly confident with how to interpret these results and understand some of the intuitions behind how interaction effects might manifest in a graph of this model's fit.

I ran 3 separate controlled studies, and **each participant participated in all 3 of the controlled studies.** For each study, they were randomly assigned to one of 2 groups (outlined in the next paragraph).

Each study has different conditions but we can model the main effects of each study using some formulation of A and B. Study 1: A=0:1, Study 2: A=0,B=0:1, Study 3: A=1,B=0,1. I don't believe I can directly compare data from study 1 -> 2 or 3 because some individual data points from those studies because they are not independent.

**My question:** Can I use the coefficients from the main effect models from these 3 studies or interpret those model's graphic representation to reason about the interaction effects of A*B?

For instance, the following graph looks like there would be an interaction effect. If it makes sense to reason this way, how can I determine if the effect is significant?
[image: Mock graphic representation of 3 separate studies]

Potentially relevant notes:

1. I'm using a zero inflated beta regression model.
2. A/B are unordered categorical variables.
3. Studies 1, 2, and 3 are not independent but the order that participants completed them is randomized.
4. Regenerating/recollecting the data to ensure independence is not suitable in my situation

Comment: I believe you can always reason about what is going on based on condition means. The independence assumption becomes important when you want to do statistical inference, i.e. when you want to generalize from your sample to a population. This involves estimating how certain you might be about the population estimate by using the sample estimate. This is what goes wrong when you don't deal with the dependence in your model because by default most methods of statistical inference assume independence.

Comment: If those are confidence intervals in your plot then they also assumed independence and might as a result be too narrow.
One popular solution to incorporating the dependence in your model is to use multilevel models. If you are using R, check out the lme4 package or the brms package.

Comment: @MrMax, Yes they were intended to be confidence intervals. I will check out multilevel models! To be clear, are you suggesting using data from both Study2 and Study3 in a multilevel model? I'm not sure if I track how this captures dependence.

Comment: yes, I am suggesting to use the data of all three studies in one model (a mixed model with random intercepts and slopes) to calculate the interaction effect along measures of statistical inference (for instance a confidence interval or a null hypothesis test) for it.
This is because when you want to compare results from the different studies you are essentially talking about the interaction effect (how does the effect differ between the three studies). And in that case you usually also want to do inference on them (how does the interaction generalize to the population?).

Comment: My attempt of answering how a mixed model captures the dependence would be that by explicitly modeling the variation between participants (using random effects) you end up with a accurate estimation of the uncertainty. This is because you basically separate which part of the information in the data is information about the general trend/effect from the part of the information which is about the participant.

Comment: Looking at your post and one of my earlier comments again, I think in your case a mixed model with random intercepts but without random slopes makes sense. 
Earlier I said random intercepts and random slopes. But the latter don't make sense because each participant was only assigned to one group per study.

Comment: @MrMax, wow this has been a lot easier than I expected! Thank you so much for your feedback and advice. For anyone else curious I basically just added a random intercepts term (1 | Participant) to my model. Is there a particularly good book or citation that explains this method that you recommend?

A simplified example in terms of the original post. Outcome ~ A + B + (1 | Participant). And one with the interaction term: Outcome ~ A * B + (1 | Participant)

Comment: @MrMax I think your comments would make for a good answer - why not turn them into one?